# Enlarge the text width and reduce the space between lines

Tags: fontsize

In fact, I want to enlarge the text as shown in the figure and reduce a little bit the space between lines
[image]

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o 
\jobname.nls}
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}

\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lscape,array}
\usepackage{framed}  
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}


\begin{frontmatter}


\title{Title of the paper hipilihoplaaa}

\author{Author 1\corref{cor}}
\ead{name@gmail.com}
\author{Author 2\corref{}}
\author{Author 3\corref{}}


\address{adress of the university}

\cortext[cor]{Corresponding author}




\begin{abstract}
elsevier’s elsarticle document class and templates can be used by academics 
to write and submit journal articles to all Elsevier journals. There are 
presently over 2,700 journals published by Elsevier with over 250,000 
articles published per year. Popular journals include Cell, The Lancet, 
Lancet Infectious Diseases and Lancet Neurology but a complete list of all 
Elsevier journals can be found here. Elsevier explicitly state that this 
class and templates are their preferred format for articles submitted to all 
of their journals.lsevier’s elsarticle document class and templates can be 
used by academics to write and submit journal articles to all Elsevier 
journals. There are presently over 2,700 journals published by Elsevier with 
over 250,000 articles published per year. Popular journals include Cell, The 
Lancet, Lancet Infectious Diseases and Lancet Neurology but a complete list 
of all Elsevier journals can be found here. Elsevier explicitly state that 
this class and templates are their preferred format for articles submitted t 
o all of their journals.lsevier’s elsarticle document class and templates 
can be used by academics to write and submit journal articles to all 
Elsevier journals. There are presently over 2,700 journals published by 
Elsevier with over 250,000 articles published per year. Popular journals 
include Cell, The Lancet, Lancet Infectious Diseases and Lancet Neurology 
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword} keyword1, keyword 2,  keyword 3,  keyword 4,  keyword 5.
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\linenumbers

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this for a journal submission? If so, why change the format? They're going to keep to their original specifications anyway...

Comment: @Werner this is the problem they are not

Comment: try if adding `\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}` increase text width. it my happen that then you not need to change size of the beseline.

Comment: Is this for an Elsevier journal? If so they're going to change the format to what they want and you're not supposed to change the format you're given to work with. And if it is a submission for another journal and they said to you you should use `elsarticle` they're going to reformat your submission, too. If you were not asked to make the changes above, don't make them. If you were in fact asked: Try what @Zarko posted, if it fails, use `\PassOptionsToPackage{hmargin=2cm}{geometry}` prior to `\documentclass`. For the linespacing: `\usepackage{setspace}\singlespacing`.

Comment: And what does mean a paper size of 25 ?

Comment: where you see 25? on image is indicated border 2 cm ... (consequently i suggest you how to change page layout with `geometry` package)

Comment: and what is the border that goes with a size of 25 in fact a journal oblige me to use a size of 25 double-spaced single-column pages with font no less than 10 (including any tables and figures).